# Does manual indexes makes sense on Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Does this simple schema makes sense on Cassandra context? Or I can just use the unique constraint index instead of a manual indexing through partition key for username and email? I understood that to guarantees normal index efficiency on Cassandra the consult must includes the partition key, so if I want to execute a "get by" on a table with millions of rows without stipulating the partition key just the index column, it may not be as fast as it should be, so the manual index by creating new partition keys become a better choice. Is this notion correct? The only problem with manual indexing is that you'll need to do it manually, if you delete a row on "users" you will need to get the respective values for the respective indexed column before deleting to be able to delete the indexes together, and may also need to batch it. Did I mis-concept Cassandra?

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  username text,
  email text,
  password_hash text,
  password_salt text,
  display_name text,
  timezone int,
  created_at timestamp,
  last_login_at timestamp
 );

 CREATE TABLE usernames (
  username text PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id uuid
 );

 CREATE TABLE user_emails (
  email text PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id uuid
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Manual indexing could an overhead, that is you need to maintain indexes along with data, while doing CRUD operations.

So its recommended to use secondary indexing support of Cassandra.

If you want to query on username and email columns then you should create secondary indexes on that columns. Secondary indexes are Cassandra inbuilt indexing mechanism to index non key columns.